How can I condense my bash script to look for 42 extensions in a directory
As the question implies, I'm struggling to condense my script to as few lines of code as possible, instead of declaring multiple if statements.
The goal of this is to create an automation script in audacity to normalize the audio of my music library. Window detection and stuff works, I'm just trying to figure out how I can condense it to run with less code.
Thank you in advance for the help.
#!/bin/bash

media=0
loop=0
cd "/home/satan/Music/.processing/"
while [[ $media -eq 0 ]]
  do
    if [[ "$media" -gt '0' ]]
    then
      break
    else
      cd *
    fi

    aa=`ls -1 *.aa 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $aa != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((aa+media))
      echo $aa "aa files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    aac=`ls -1 *.aac 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $aac != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((aac+media))
      echo $aac "aac files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    aax=`ls -1 *.aax 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $aax != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((aax+media))
      echo $aax "aax files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    act=`ls -1 *.act 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $act != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((act+media))
      echo $act "act files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    aiff=`ls -1 *.aiff 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $aiff != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((aiff+media))
      echo $aiff "aiff files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    alac=`ls -1 *.alac 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $alac != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((alac+media))
      echo $alac "alac files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    ape=`ls -1 *.ape 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $ape != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((ape+media))
      echo $ape "ape files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    au=`ls -1 *.au 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $au != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((au+media))
      echo $au "au files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    dss=`ls -1 *.dss 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $dss != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((dss+media))
      echo $dss "dss files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    dvf=`ls -1 *.dvf 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $dvf != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((dvf+media))
      echo $dvf "dvf files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    flac=`ls -1 *.flac 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $flac != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((flac+media))
      echo $flac "flac files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    gsm=`ls -1 *.gsm 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $gsm != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((gsm+media))
      echo $gsm "gsm files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    iklax=`ls -1 *.iklax 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $iklax != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((iklax+media))
      echo $iklax "iklax files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    ivs=`ls -1 *.ivs 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $ivs != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((ivs+media))
      echo $ivs "ivs files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    m4a=`ls -1 *.m4a 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $m4a != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((m4a+media))
      echo $m4a "m4a files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    m4b=`ls -1 *.m4b 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $m4b != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((m4b+media))
      echo $m4b "m4b files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    m4p=`ls -1 *.m4p 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $m4p != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((m4p+media))
      echo $m4p "m4p files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    mmf=`ls -1 *.mmf 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $mmf != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((mmf+media))
      echo $mmf "mmf files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    movpkg=`ls -1 *.movpkg 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $movpkg != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((movpkg+media))
      echo $movpkg "movpkg files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    mpc=`ls -1 *.mpc 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $mpc != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((mpc+media))
      echo $mpc "mpc files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    mp3=`ls -1 *.mp3 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $mp3 != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((mp3+media))
      echo $mp3 "mp3 files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    msv=`ls -1 *.msv 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $msv != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((msv+media))
      echo $msv "act files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    nmf=`ls -1 *.nmf 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $nmf != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((nmf+media))
      echo $nmf "nmf files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    ogg=`ls -1 *.ogg 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $ogg != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((ogg+media))
      echo $ogg "ogg files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    oga=`ls -1 *.oga 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $oga != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((oga+media))
      echo $oga "oga files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    mogg=`ls -1 *.mogg 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $mogg != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((mogg+media))
      echo $mogg "mogg files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    opus=`ls -1 *.opus 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $opus != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((opus+media))
      echo $opus "opus files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    ra=`ls -1 *.ra 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $ra != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((ra+media))
      echo $ra "ra files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    rm=`ls -1 *.rm 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $rm != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((rm+media))
      echo $rm "rm files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    raw=`ls -1 *.raw 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $raw != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((raw+media))
      echo $raw "raw files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    rt64=`ls -1 *.rt64 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $rt64 != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((rt64+media))
      echo $rt64 "rt64 files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    sln=`ls -1 *.sln 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $sln != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((sln+media))
      echo $sln "sln files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    tta=`ls -1 *.tta 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $tta != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((tta+media))
      echo $tta "tta files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    voc=`ls -1 *.voc 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $voc != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((voc+media))
      echo $voc "voc files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    vox=`ls -1 *.vox 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $vox != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((vox+media))
      echo $vox "vox files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    wav=`ls -1 *.wav 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $wav != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((wav+media))
      echo $wav "wav files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    wma=`ls -1 *.wma 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $wma != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((wma+media))
      echo $wma "wma files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    webm=`ls -1 *.webm 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $webm != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((webm+media))
      echo $webm "webm files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    cda=`ls -1 *.cda 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $cda != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((cda+media))
      echo $cda "cda files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    threegp=`ls -1 *.3gp 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $threegp != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((threegp+media))
      echo $threegp "3gp files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

    eightsvx=`ls -1 *.8svx 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $eightsvx != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((eightsvx+media))
      echo $eightsvx "8svx files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi
done
nohup pcmanfm >/dev/null 2>&1 &


Regarding while [[ $media -eq 0 ]]   do     if [[ "$media" -gt '0' ]] - media can't be greater than 0 at the start of a loop that is only [re-]entered when media equals 0 so please [edit] your question to explain what you're trying to do with that if statement. Also explain what cd * is intended to do.

Your choice of user name in cd "/home/... at the top of your script may be off-putting to some readers why may otherwise want to help you but don't want to post anything using that name, you might want to choose a less controversial name such as bob

The bash for loop can handle this.
suffixes="aa aac aax ..."
for suffix in $suffixes
do
    this=`ls -1 *.$suffix 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $this != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((this+media))
      echo $this " files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi
done


I will give this a go man, one last thing to add, where should I add "cd *" to switch the directories if it can be found in said directory?

Also I have run the for loop, works as excepted, would a while loop as a function to switch directories help?

Never mind figured it out! thank you! Much appreciation to add to my library of bash code!

You should copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it'll tell you about.

i) you really shouldn't use ls for this (at least not without some extra options and a modern ls), ii) you should quote your variables and use an array here, iii) the -1  option is unnecessary, ls always prints one entry per line when piped to something else.

I couldn't figure out what you're trying to do with your loop and media variables or the cd * but, otherwise, this seems to be what you're trying to do:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

media=0
loop=0
cd '/home/whatever/' || exit 1

sfxs=( aa aac aax ... 8svx )
for sfx in "${sfxs[@]}"; do
    files=( *."$sfx" )
    numFiles="${#files[@]}"
    if (( numFiles != 0 )); then
        media=$(( numFiles + media ))
        printf '%d %s files found in %s\n' "$numFiles" "$sfx" "$PWD"
        printf '\n'
        printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
        printf '\n'
    fi
done

nohup pcmanfm >/dev/null 2>&1 &

Obviously replace ... with the rest of the suffixes you're interested in BUT you maybe would prefer a script that just uses whatever suffixes exist in your directory rather than hard-coding a list in your script, e.g. using GNU sed and GNU sort for -z:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

media=0
loop=0
cd '/home/whatever/' || exit 1

sfxs=( $(printf '%s\0' *.* | sed -z 's/.*\.//' | sort -zu | tr '\0' '\n') )

for sfx in "${sfxs[@]}"; do
    files=( *."$sfx" )
    numFiles="${#files[@]}"
    media=$(( numFiles + media ))
    printf '%d %s files found in %s\n' "$numFiles" "$sfx" "$PWD"
    printf '\n'
    printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
    printf '\n'
done

nohup pcmanfm >/dev/null 2>&1 &

Both of the above are untested.

If you don't mind switching to the Z shell (zsh) then you can do this much more compactly.
For example, given an array files=( *.*(N) ) of all the non-hidden files with "dot extensions" in the current directory, you can get an array of their unique extensions as ${(u)files:e}, and you can get an array of all the filenames matching a given extension .ext using ${(M)files:#*.ext}. Putting it together and adding the # flag to get the number of elements in each result:
#!/usr/bin/zsh

files=( *.*(N) )

for ext ( ${(u)files:e} ) 
  printf '%d %s files found in %s\n' ${#${(M)files:#*.$ext}} $ext $PWD

If you prefer, you can put the loop in an anonymous function and call it on the glob expansion directly:
(){ for ext ( ${(u)@:e} ) 
      printf '%d %s files found in %s\n' ${#${(M)@:#*.$ext}} $ext $PWD
  } *.*(N)


TL;DR: Use the extract-function refactoring to reduce duplicated code like your 41 if-statements. Or use Bash's array-expansion to count all file-types as one-liner.
Code smell and refactoring
You spotted 41 times a very similar code-block. We call this a code-smell: duplicated code.
This is the code-block that is duplicated (only specific difference is the file-extension):
    aa=`ls -1 *.aa 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $aa != 0 ]
    then
      media=$((aa+media))
      echo $aa "aa files found in"
      pwd
      echo
      ls -1
      echo
    fi

Code-duplication and extract-function
The recommended refactoring for code-duplication is extract-function.
Let's write a function that takes the media file-extension like aa (for .aa files) as parameter and return the result (i.e. the file count for this extension):
count_files_with_extension() {
    # returns the file-count as integer
    # use with file-extension as argument like:
    # num = count_files_with_extension("aa")
    extension = $1
    file_count = `ls -1 *.$extension 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $file_count != 0 ]
    then
      echo "$file_count .$extension files found in $(pwd)"
    fi
    return file_count
}

Note: To condense the output I removed the file-listing output echo;ls -1;echo and inlined the pwd.
The previous count accumulation like media=$((aa+media)) can be achieved by adding the return value:
media_count = $((media_count + count_files_with_extension("aa")))

Loop
Next, reuse this function in a loop as answered by rfm already:
suffixes="aa aac aax ..."  # all 41 extensions specified without dot, separated by space
for suffix in $suffixes
do
  media_count = $((media_count + count_files_with_extension("$suffix")))
done

See also: Loop through an array of strings in Bash? - Stack Overflow.
Complete and Simplified Script
#!/bin/bash
count_files_with_extension() {
    # returns the file-count as integer
    # use with file-extension as argument like:
    # num = count_files_with_extension("aa")
    extension = $1
    file_count = `ls -1 *.$extension 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $file_count != 0 ]
    then
      echo "$file_count '.$extension' files found in $(pwd)"
    fi
    return file_count
}

cd "/home/satan/Music/.processing/"
suffixes = "aa aac aax ..."  # all 41 extensions specified without dot, separated by space

media_count = 0
for suffix in $suffixes
do
  media_count = $((media_count + count_files_with_extension("$suffix")))
done

echo "Total media files found: $media_count" 

Alternative: Bash's array expansion with ls to count files
Usually you can use brace-expansion to specify ranges that are expanded by Bash. For example ls *.{mp3,aac} gets expanded to a sequence of 2 commands executed in order: ls *.mp3; ls *.aac.
You also can use parentheses to assign arrays like suffixes=(mp3 aac) and without braces expand these array elements in a command like ls *.$suffixes.
Together we can simplify the count of files by all given file-extensions to:
suffixes=(aa aac aax ...)  # all 41 extensions specified as array in parentheses, separated by space

media_count = `ls *.$suffixes 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
echo "Total media files found: $media_count"

This prints the total count of all files found by given suffixes.
References

Refactoring Guru, Code Smells: Duplicate Code
Fowler, Refactoring: Extract Function

